# How to order by within group. with additional use of concate_ws and collect_set in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have data in this format 
I am putting **** in phrase column for security reasons. This is basically a sentence by party. 
[image: Data]

This is the ordered conversation for 1 particular ID.

I want to achieve this result :
Again *** instead of sentence. 
[image: result]

The query I am using to achieve this :

```
select tmp.interaction_id,collect_set(tmp.final) from
(select interaction_id,concat_ws(':--  ',party,phrase) as 
final,start_offset,end_offset  from aads_piim.A608232_Myvoice_wt_transcript
 where interaction_id=26951370
order by start_offset,end_offset) as tmp
group by tmp.interaction_id;
```

Here I am able ti do this because I am sorting for only 1 ID. then the conversation is ordered correctly. like the agent and customer sequence. 
I have around 400K records like this. I want to do the similar for them. 
The query I am using for this is :

```
create table aads_piim.a608232_myvoice_transcript_combined as
select tmp.interaction_id,collect_set(tmp.final) as final_trans from
(select interaction_id,concat_ws(':--  ',party,phrase) as 
final,start_offset,end_offset  from aads_piim.A608232_Myvoice_wt_transcript 
order by start_offset,end_offset) as tmp
group by tmp.interaction_id;
```

But here while sorting it is considering all IDs. 
My question is How to sort within IDS. Means how do I group by ID and order by the offset column for that particular ID in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort by interaction_id followed by the offsets.

```
select interaction_id,concat_ws(':--  ',party,phrase) as final,start_offset,end_offset  
from aads_piim.A608232_Myvoice_wt_transcript 
order by interaction_id,start_offset,end_offset
```